# Javascript - referring to the instantiated object

Tags: javascript, function, class, this

Let's say I have a javascript function as follows:

```
car.prototype = {
    this.stolen = "",

    initialize: function(){
        this.stolen = false;
    },

    steal: function(){
        Event.observe(window, "resize", function(){
            this.stolen = true;
        });
    }
}
```

In the `steal` method, how can I refer to the `stolen` property of the `car` object within the `Event.observe()` method?  In the code above, `this` in the `Event.observe()` method is referring to the window instead of the `car` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function:

```
Event.observe(window, "resize", (function(){
    this.stolen = true;
}).bind(this));
```